# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test ReactJs components, where one of them has a method in which it fetches data, the fetch has a promise in it.. So I tried to create a mock file:

```
  const apiFetch = {
      value() {
        return 42
      },
    }

module.exports = apiFetch
```

then:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(apiFetch, 'value')

const isValue = apiFetch.value()

expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()

expect(isValue).toBe(42)
```

The test is passing, but this warning is still showing.

I added one more thing:

```
process.on('UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning', (e) => { throw e })
```

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 188)

Comment: The question doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Where is that rejected promise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When running async tests you should keep in mind that you need to indicate the test method when it has finished.

With jest you can do something like:

apiFetch.js

```
const apiFetch = {
    value() {
        return Promise.resolve(42);
    },
}

module.exports = apiFetch
```

apiFetch.test.js:

```
const apiFetch = require('./apiFetch');

test('the data is peanut butter', done => {
    apiFetch.value().then(data => {
        expect(data).toBe(42);
        done();
    })
});
```

done is an injected function parameter (provided by the jest framework) that when called, indicates the end of the test method.

If you're testing async logic without using the async features of jest (or mocha) then tests will pass even though the async promises fail

**edit**

Each framework has promise support. With jest it is something like

```
it('works with resolves', () => {
   expect.assertions(1);
   return expect(apiFetch.value()).resolves.toEqual(42);
});
```

When working with pure callbacks, use the injected done.

When working with promises you could use the injected 'done' function, but if the promise fails and 'done' is not called, then the test will fail on timeout. With jest it is recommended to work with 'it' , 'expect' and 'resolve' when testing promise logic.

Comment: All modern testing frameworks support promises. The code you've provided will result in test timeout *and* unhandled rejection warning in case of failed test. Don't use `done` with promises, it's just wrong.

Comment: @estus thanks for the remark. You're right. I've edited the answer