# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning : jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, axios, enzyme

When I tried to run the below code for testing my axios request using jest, I'm getting the following warning, even though my tests are passing.

```
fetchNoteHandler = async () => {    
        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.props.idToken
        }
        return axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/notes/${this.state.noteId}`, {
            headers: headers,
            cancelToken: this.source.token
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                noteId: response.data["noteId"],
                heading: response.data["noteHeading"],
                note: response.data["noteBody"],
                lastUpdated: response.data["lastUpdated"],
                fetchingNow: false
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            if (!axios.isCancel(error)) {
                this.setState({
                    fetchingNow: false,
                    error: "Failed to fetch note"
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

The function fetchNoteHandler() is called from componentDidUpdate().

```
it('should ', (done) => {
    let fetchSuccess;
    const axiosSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockImplementation(() => {
        const thenFn = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce((onfulfilled) => {
            fetchSuccess = onfulfilled;
        })
        return { then: thenFn }
    })
    
    const wrapper = setup({ auth: authUpdatedState }, { location: { search: { id: randomNoteId }}})
    expect(axiosSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    fetchSuccess(sampleResponse);
    done();
});
```

```
(node:69127) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:69127) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:69127) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How can I handle unhandled promises in this case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614618/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning/51615151

Comment: You didn't mock Axios correctly, it doesn't return a promise but some promise-like object that doesn't have `catch` method. You didn't post the component you test but it appears that it uses `catch` which you didn't provide. Also the test will become asynchronous and should be tested with promises, not `done`. I'd suggest to not reinvent the wheel and use some existing solution to mock Axios, like Moxios.

Comment: @Estus Flask I'm really confused on how to test the above function. Could you please write a sample code for this?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you don't catch errors in your test nor returned a `Promise`. Try it like this:

```
const axiosSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockImplementationOnce(() => 
    Promise.resolve(yourMockData)
);
```